# Get images from Gopro sdcard Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

does anyone know how I get images from the sdcard?

is possible any other way, or just this one?

http : / / 10 . 5 . 5 . 9 : 8080/DCIM/100GOPRO/ " .

all the best.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you summarize the issue? What does your code look like currently? Take a look at the guide on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

I tried to read the html that is generated, and parse. 
Runs, but memory overflow. 
And I was wondering if anyone knows another way to read the image gallery from GoPro.

My code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"h t t p : / / 10 . 5 . 5 . 9 : 8 0 8 0 /DCIM/100GOPRO/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error;
    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:htmlString error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];

        NSArray *inputNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"a"];

        for (HTMLNode *inputNode in inputNodes) {

            NSString *fileName = [inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"href"];
            NSString *fileExtension = [fileName substringFromIndex:fileName.length-4];

            if ([[fileExtension uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@".JPG"]) {
                if(![_photosNameList containsObject:[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"href"]]){

                    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"href"] relativeToURL:URL];

                    //UIImageView *photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,192,192)];

                    [_photosList addObject:imageURL];
                    [_photosNameList addObject:fileName];

                }
            }
        }
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }

    //[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(refreshGoProPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[op start];
```